# Grouping models by field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Consider a simple Django model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField()
    b = models.CharField()
```

And a query that fetches them in a view:

```
objs = MyModel.objects.all()
```

Now here's the tricky part, the template should render objects that have the same `a` field together. So if I have three objects:

`{a:'1', b:'5'}, {a:'1', b:'8'}, {a:'2', b:'4'}`

they should render like this in the output:

- a=1

  - b=5
  - b=8
- a=2, b=4

Basically, I need to group objects by their `a` field and render those groups differently than objects that have unique `a` fields.

How should I go about grouping these objects and displaying them differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order them by the `a` field, then do the grouping in the template with the [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag.

Code example:

```
{% regroup objs by a as objs_list %}
<ul>
  {% for a in objs_list %}
    {% if a.list|length == 1 %}
    <li>{{ a.grouper }}, {{ a.list.0.b }}</li>
    {% else %}
    <li>{{ a.grouper }}
      <ul>
      {% for obj in a.list %}
        <li>{{ obj.b }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
     {% endif %}
   </li>
   {% endfor %}      
</ul>
```

Comment: I had a feeling you would be the first to respond ;) Just didn't know it would be that fast. Thanks!

Comment: Daniel, any idea how I can check the groupers such that those with a single element would be rendered differently?